# Range in File Java

Tags: java, file, range

I have a problem. So I have a txt file, where is some datas. I have a class `PatientView` with method `readInRange(PatientModel pm, Integer a, Integer b)` and this class `PatientModel` with getter methods and one private method `writeToFile()` and I have a problem with this method `readInRange` cause I don't know how to output information between two numbers(this range must work with `mediacalCard` field). So what should I do to display the range using `mediacalCard` field? Should I make this `mediacalCard` an array? Please help me.

This is my code:

Class `PatientView`:

```
public void readInRange(PatientModel pm, Integer a, Integer b) {
    try {
        String str;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        for (int i = a; i < b+1; i++) {
            while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Class `PatientModel` and his getter methods and write to file method:

```
public Integer getId() {
    return Id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getPatronymic() {
    return patronymic;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public Integer getNumberPhone() {
    return numberPhone;
}

public Integer getMedicalCard() {
    return medicalCard;
}

public String getDiagnose() {
    return diagnose;
}

private void writeToFile() {
    try(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt", true))) {
        bufferedWriter.write(String.format("%1d, %10s, %10s, %10s, %10s, %10d, %10d, %10s", Id, firstName,
                lastName, patronymic, Address, numberPhone, medicalCard, diagnose));
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment and the code you provided has nothing to do with the problem you've described, you've had.

Comment: @Lothar I tried using `if(a < pm.getMedicalCard() && b > pm.getMedicalCard())` but it doesn't work

Comment: A solution would be to use the [Range class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html) if using an external library is an option and I'm not sure I fully understand the requirement but I think the loop from readInRange method needs to be changed, as currently reads from line 0 until the line b - a

Comment: @ValentinCarnu I tried this `if(range.contains(pm.getMedicalCard()))` but I always get a NullPointerException.

Comment: You should post what you've tried.  If your looking for records inside the range, I see two potential issues.  The first is I can't tell if your converting the medicalCard fields to some sort of number after reading the record.  Your if statement probably isn't doing what you think it's doing.  The real problem is that your probably comparing strings, so your if statement wouldn't work at all, but you haven't posted enough of the class to tell.  You should also change your variables to be more descriptive, is a the low range or the high range. Change a and b to be something like low and high.

Comment: @Lado Is a bit unclear for me. My assumption is that the `readInRange` method should read from test.txt file a range of lines defined by the medicalCard. Is my assumption right?

Comment: @ValentinCarnu yes you're right.

Comment: @Lado ok, then in `PatienModel` the `medicalCard` should be a Range instead of an Integer and then there should be something like this `PatienModel pm = new PatienModel(); pm.setMedicalCard(Range.between(10, 21));` before calling the `readInRange` method. The `readInRange` method should loop between `pm.getMedicalCard().getMinimum()` and `pm.getMedicalCard().getMaximum()`. Still the loop inside the `readInRange` method needs to be changed as currently doesn't read the lines in range but rather the lines from 0 to maximum - minimum. P.S. the range values (10 and 21) are just examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody who tried to help me. This is how I solved this problem

My code:

```
public void readInRange(PatientModel pm, Integer low, Integer high) {
    String[] splitdata;
    String sixcol; Integer num=0;
    try {
        String str;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            splitdata = str.split("[,\t]");
            sixcol = splitdata[0];
            Integer aa = num.valueOf(sixcol);
            if(aa > low && aa < high) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: the `PatientModel pm` parameter is not used, the method reads from the *test.txt* file all the lines and outputs only the lines in the range defined by *a* and *b* no matter the value of medicalCard property of pm parameter. Something is missing either from the description of the problem or from the solution